# How can I test for trend across ordinal groups in Stata?

Tags: stata, ordinal-data, trend

I have 4k observations on individuals distributed across 10 ordinal categories of socio-economic position (1 being worst, 10 - best).

What kind of statistical test could I use in Stata to judge if there is a trend across these ten ordinal categories when it comes to:

1. Continuous variable (income)?
2. Ordinal categorical variable (response coded from 0 'difficult' to 11 'easy')

Thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both situations, you can use the [nptrend](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?nptrend) command

```
nptrend income, by(socecopos)
```

Alternatively you could also test for a monotonic trend by using [spearman's rank correlation](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?spearman):

```
spearman income socecopos
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks promising, however nptrend seems to have some [issues](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2003-11/msg00506.html) when it comes to scaling.

Comment: Yes, but on the same page you find a link to a possible solution ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Some other pointers from around the Web:

- Stata's [website](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/stat/trend.html) suggests modelling using [regress](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?regress) command.
- Same website also suggests using [vwls](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?vwls) command for Variance-weighted least squares.
- Roger Newson (on [statalist](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2003-11/msg00510.html)) suggested [somersd](http://ideas.repec.org/c/boc/bocode/s336401.html) package ([article](http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=snp15_6) in Stata Journal), however I wasn't able to find my way around this solution.