# Hypothesis testing in ordinal data

Tags: ordinal-data

Suppose I want to compare how different categories of deprivation or education differs between two groups. Deprivation and education are obviously ordinal variables, in this hypothetical example let's say there are 10 levels (deciles) for deprivation, and 5 levels for highest education (primary, secondary, apprenticeship, university, higher degree). What test should I use? And should different tests be applied to deprivation/education? I've seen papers use Chi-squared and Ranksum tests (which I don't feel are correct but wouldn't be "wrong" according to some entry level stats books) and also tests for trend ("nptrend" in stata) but don't get the intuition for why.

Are there more subtleties with regard to the nature of and number of categories of ordinal variables?

Answer (score 1):

One test (not the only one) you could use is the Jonckheere Terpstra test.  This compares ordinal data to either nominal or ordinal data.

Comment: +1 i understand this is another test for trend; how does this differ from the "non-parametric test for trend" and what is it / are they actually testing?

Comment: Which nonparametric test for trend?  You can look up any test and find out what it does.  Wikipedia usually has good articles on these, e.g for [JT test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonckheere%27s_trend_test).  Then if you have a more specific question, you can ask it here.

Comment: Stata's "nptrend" [command](http://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stata/faq/how-can-i-test-for-a-trend-across-a-categorical-variable/) is attributed to Cuzick. @Stephen Duffield you may find [this](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/test-for-trend/) helpful as I did.

Comment: or [this CV post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-can-i-test-for-trend-across-ordinal-groups-in-stata) and [this page](http://math.usu.edu/jrstevens/biostat/projects2013/pres_OrdNonpar.pdf)